# Will this Android studio warning lead to any error in the Future?(Should it be considered for troubleshooting?)

Tags: java, android-studio, warnings, daemon

```
Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
        E:\Android\Android Studio\jre
        Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
        spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
        while using Android Studio.
        More info...
        Select a JDK from the File System
        Do not show this warning again
```

The above is the warning that I am getting, Should I specify the the directory where the Java JDK is installed manually in the Android studio?
What does this problem imply to?

Answer (score 0):

I have personally never had problems with this error. However, you might have to choose the directory if in case you copy the project to a new system. It's better to install JDK from the official repo and give the system path in the settings.